# mistake in vector showing

Tags: c++, vector

I have two simple classes. I want with vector show result, but number is not showed. On the other hand, when I try result without vector, result will be show. Can you help me? Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;


template<typename T>
class One
{
protected:
    T word;
    T word2;

public:
    One() {word = "0"; word2 = "0";}
    One(T w, T w2) {word = w; word2 = w2;}
    virtual const void Show() {cout << word << endl; cout << word2 << endl;}
};

template<typename T>
class Two : public One<T>
{
private:
    int number;
public:
    Two() {number = 0;}
    Two(T w, T w2, int n) : One(w,w2) {number = n;}
    virtual const void Show () {cout << word << endl; cout << word2 << endl; cout << number << endl; }
};


int main ()
{
    One<string> *idk;
    Two<string> *something = new Two<string>("asd","aa",1);
    idk = something;

    idk->Show(); // OK - asd, aa, 1

    vector<One<string>> arr;
    arr.push_back(*idk); 
    arr.at(0).Show(); // WRONG - asd,aa
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [What is the Slicing Problem in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c/274634#274634)

Comment: `: One(w, w2) { number = n; }` I think should be `: One<T>(w, w2) {number = n;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing `One<string>` instances instead that pointers to them `One<string>*`.

Since the object is stored totally in the vector cell, there is no polymorphism as the object suffers from [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing): any additional feature that inherits from `One` in the instance you are placing inside the vector is just discarded.

Try with a `vector<One<string>*>` so that a pointer is stored and the problem doesn't occur. Mind that, to manage memory, using a [smart pointer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) when working with STL collections is a wise choice.

Answer (score 0):

Your vector stores `One<string>` objects. When you `push_back(*idk)`, a new `One<string>` object is created via a copy constructor from `*idk`.

If you want to keep the virtual behavior, you should use a vector of pointers: `vector<One<string>*> arr;` and then `arr.push_back(idk);`.